# DSL-Tools for web-applications

Tags: web-applications, dsl

I am searching for domain-specific-language-tools for web-applications.
Tools which generate most of the HTML-code out of models and textual descriptions.
Have you ever worked with such tools und what are your impressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMl or Web Modeling Language was de facto standard for model driven development of web application but recently the company behind WebML has merge it into new standard called IFML. Interaction flow Modeling Language .
[www.webratio.com](http://www.webratio.com)